# Importing CSV in Python and manipulating the data

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm new to programming and I need to do some (maybe very basic) stuff but I'm really struggling with it.
I have some CSV-files, when opened in excel it consits of somewhat 1500 rows and 500 columns and its all numbers except for the first element of the first row (some kind of header). I need to do stuff like avareging over the elements of the first 60 rows and adding and substracting complete rows.

I'm having a bit of trouble with importing the files. When I just use readcsv and then add them to an empty dataset row bu row I get the desired format (list of rows?) but all the elements are strings instead of floats (maybe because the first element in the file is a string?) and I can't get them to convert to floats so maybe you can help me out a little.

Another thing is how do I actually manipulate a certain part of the data, like a loop going through a certain amount of rows. I can't really figure it out since mathmatical things on string dont work.

Thanks in advance for your help and comments!

Comment: It will help if you post the code you are using. have you checked out the module `pandas`? it is designed for data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following and it works fine:

```
import numpy 
csv = numpy.loadtxt('something.csv', delimiter = ',')
```

If you want to skip the first row, you can do like this:

```
csv = numpy.loadtxt('something.csv', delimiter = ',', skiprows = 1)
```

And if you want to operate on the first 60 rows:

```
X = csv[:60,:]
```

Then you just use X for what you want.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that if the 1st cell is string whole column is of the string type... That may be the label of that column. Try accessing the data from the 2nd row or explicitly name the column

for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [10,20]})
print df
```

output

```
   $a  $b
0   1   10
1   2   20
```

you can change the name of the column by

```
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
```

output

```
    a   b
0   1   10
1   2   20
```

and after changing the name you can access the column as df['a'] or af['b']

Comment: Yes, pandas is a great way to do that, but it has 500 columns, how can you access them all by name? just saying :P

Comment: coool :D But  soon we should find a way that could label the dataset :D ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) in pandas dataframe.

1. Following codes will automatically recognize your header and set the headers as column names.

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   data = pd.read_csv('Your file name.csv')
   ```
2. Regarding your problem of string format of data, there is no way to help you without some sample data.
3. *I need to do stuff like averaging over the elements of the first 60 rows and adding and subtracting complete rows.*

   for averaging the first 60 rows, you can do something like this:

   ```
      import pandas as pd

      lst1 = range(100)
      lst2 = range(100,200)
      lst3 = range(200,300)

      data = pd.DataFrame({'a': lst1,'b': lst2,'c': lst3})
      data_avrg = data[:60].mean()

      In[20]:data_avrg
      Out[20]: 
      a     29.5
      b    129.5
      c    229.5
      dtype: float64
   ```

   If you want to add or subtract the average of 60 rows to the complete rows, like all rows in column a, you can do this:

   ```
     data['a_add'] = data.a + data_avrg.a
     data['a_subtract'] = data.a - data_avrg.a
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It actually imports it very nicely now, I can work with this!